# What is 3 % 4 in Python?

Tags: python

What is 3 % 4 in Python? I.e. I don't know what the outcome is if:

1. the remainder is a fraction (whereas the operands are non-fractions)
2. the first operand < the second operand

Comment: How can the remainder be a fraction if the operands are non-fractions?

Comment: @David I think OP knows what the result is, but is asking about what the operator is supposed to do.

Comment: Surely, the definition of remainder could be discussed on http://math.stackexchange.com/.  It might make more sense there than here.

Comment: You...can't really divide fractions and get remainders.  Or else I'm forgetting that part of algebra?

Comment: now the question is can anyone rock the +20?

Comment: Who ever wrote the comment, yes JavaScript can compute modulo of fractions :) (PHP can't). Anyway, the comment was not meant to so serious. Just that `%` is not special to Python (I deleted the comment, it was *The same as in PHP and JavaScript*.)

Comment: @ryebr3ad: In Python, you can ;)

Comment: @Felix in Python % is also overloaded as string formatting, which might be the source of some confusion.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: True, I meant in this context when dealing with numbers.... seems people are very picky tonight ;)

Comment: @delnan: freakin' Python...I guess I should finally learn it.

Answer (score 6):

The % sign is the modulus operator. A quick example:

```
C:\Users\jon>python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3%4
3
>>> 4%3
1
>>> 4.5%3
1.5
>>> 4%3.5
0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

1) the result of a modulus operation cannot be a fraction if both operands are integers.

2) If `x < y`, then `x % y` will be equal to `x` (assuming they are positive).

Comment: It can be a fraction, but only if one of the inputs is a fraction.

Comment: His question 1) states that the operands are non fractions. In that case, it will always be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mod operator -- not unique to Python at all, but pretty much a staple in all modern programming languages.  It's the remainder of an integer division.  So...yeah, 3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Python, but I know this:

3 = 0 * 4 + 3. The quotient is 0 and the remainder is 3.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is 3! (don't read: 3 factorial)

Answer (score 0):

The first case is impossible.
For the second case, it's just the first operand: `3 % 4 == 3`.

Comment: The remainder when dividing two integers cannot be a fraction, by definition. In Python, the operands *can* be non-integral, in which case so will the remainder be (e.g. `3.5 % 4 == 3.5`, `4.5 % 4 == 0.5` and `5 % 4.5 == 0.5`).